# After Login Execute A Function And Redirect To Previous Page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I've created a page like `all_elements`, which contains `list of elements` and provided an option to `adding an element to wishlist`.

The steps are as follows.

1. If the user is logged in, the element is adding to wishlist through an `ajax call`.
2. If the user is not logged in, it has to ask an user to login.
3. After the login is success, the element has to `added to wishlist` and redirect to `all_elements page`.

I'm trying following steps.

1. If the user is not logged in, saving the link for adding an element to wishlist and redirecting to login page.
2. After login success, its redirecting to `all_elements page`. But I'm checking every time the `session link which included adding course to wishlist`.

But I'm thinking this is bad coding because every time I need to check the session link in `all_elements page`.

Please suggest me good solution and the work would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you but it sounds like you want to store the element the user is trying to add and once they log in successfully you want to add that element and redirect them to the all_elements page that would include the element they just added? Is that right?

Comment: @JacobCarter Yes you're exactly correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, This is done with a GET paramter to the login page( as POST paramter if the form is ajaxy).

For example, Assume I want to click somewhere that requires login, That links i called www.example.com/secret.

You can store the URI segment (or the whole URL) as $_GET param, as soon as you login your function check if $_GET['redirect'] exists, if it does, try to redirect to it.

This way the 'redirect' logic is embeded in the login itself, and not in any other functionality, this allows you to extend this functionality to any other part of the website, instead of checking the session.

This can also be done using the session, storing the link in a $_SESSION['redirect'] variable.
In anyway, These checks should be done after login, and not in any single page